# Requiring a file inside a module context

Tags: ruby

I have a module called *WG* that all classes inside my application are inside, purely for the purposes of namespacing, so I don't have naming collisions with outside code.

My issue is that every class in my application then needs to be specified as being inside that module, and that's a pain, mainly because it adds one indent level to *all* code in my application.

In other words, here's a typical class, in a file called "Thing.rb"

```
module WG
  class Thing
    def do_things
    end
  end
end
```

In my mind, there should be some way of requiring that file *inside* the context of the *WG* module, so that I can forego the line at the top and at the end, and the mandatory one-level indentation.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't understand the line - ***so that I can forego the line at the top and at the end, and the mandatory one-level indentation.***. Can you bit clarify this line?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `::` operator:

```
class WG::Thing
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Hmm... that kinda worked, except now all references to other constants inside the WG namespace within that class need to be prefixed with `WG::`. Any way around that?

Comment: @MattParlane: Hmm, not that I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't. `require`ing a file simply runs the file as-is.

`load` allows you to run the code inside the context of an anonymous module, but not a specific one. Of course, you can still access the global namespace by using the `::` scope resolution operator.